# E-Iceblue Spire PDF Free Jenkins Timeout

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, gradle, timeout

I'm trying to use the Spire Free PDF library from the E-Iceblue repository and it just takes too long for the dependency to be downloaded on my computer. The big problem is that I use Jenkins for CI/CD and it gives me a timeout error:

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not download spire.doc.free-3.9.0.jar (e-iceblue:spire.doc.free:3.9.0)
   > Could not get resource 'http://repo.e-iceblue.com/nexus/content/groups/public/e-iceblue/spire.doc.free/3.9.0/spire.doc.free-3.9.0.jar'.
      > Read timed out
```

I tried to increase the timeout using these two properties in the Gradle Wrapper, but without success:
`/gradlew build -Dorg.gradle.internal.http.socketTimeout=60000 -Dorg.gradle.internal.http.connectionTimeout=60000 jacocoTestReport`

On my personal computer, it takes around 5 minutes to download the dependency. On my work computer, where I have the VPN provided by my company, the download time is the same: 4-5 minutes. The Jenkins that I'm using is hosted by my company to manage different projects and the Gradle file looks like this:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "http://repo.e-iceblue.com/nexus/content/groups/public/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'e-iceblue', name: 'spire.doc.free', version: '3.9.0'
}
```

Is there something I can do to fix this issue? Or maybe there is a problem with the repository itself?

Comment: Hi, Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use "https" instead of "http":

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://repo.e-iceblue.com/nexus/content/groups/public/"
    }
}
```